# Python: numpy.var yields unknown number

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.var yields this number: 6.0037250324777306e-28.

I suppose by looking at the data that this number is close to 0. Am I correct? If so, how could I interpret this number?

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation; this isn't really a programming question, but that number is `0.000000000000000000000000000600` in a format you may be more familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a number very very close to 0. For example:

```
import numpy as np
list_to_check_var = [2,2,2,2,2.00000000001]
np.var(list_to_check_var)
```

yields

```
1.6000002679246418e-23
```

As you intuitively know, the variance of the list is very small. The `e-23` part at the end means you need to multiply the number with `10^-23`.